# Mat Image creation from raw buffer data

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have float x, float y, float z values of an image. I want to construct a 16 bit png depth image by copying the z values.   The image I am getting as a result has some invalid points. Below is my code.

```
 uint16_t* depthValues = new uint16_t[size];
auto sampleVector(DepthPoints);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sampleVector.size(); i++)
    {
        depthValues[i] = (sampleVector.at(i).z) * 65536;
    }
  Mat newDepthImage = cv::Mat(var.height, var.width, CV_16UC1,depthValues);
imwrite(Location, CImage);
```

Can someone tell me, if I can copy the float values into an unsigned char array to create the image? 
Is that why my image has invalid points?

Comment: What "result has some invalid points" exactly means? Is the range of z values `[0 - 1]` ? If z has values `>1`, everything above 1 will be 65535.

Comment: some areas of the image are dark. I was not very sure if the float data can be copied to `uint16_t* `. Is that how we can create a depth image?

Comment: What's the range of `z` values? Maybe all you need is `depthValues[i] = static_cast<uint16_t>(sampleVector.at(i).z);` BTW, x,y,z refers to R,G,B?

Comment: x,y,z refers to the (x,y,z) coordinate. The data is from a point cloud.

Comment: Again, what's the range of z values?

Comment: are all you float values between 0 and 1?

Comment: is size == var.width*var.height?

Comment: its float value somewhere between [0.0-4.0]

Comment: is size == sampleVector.size()?

Comment: @Micka : yes. Size is height*width

Comment: I am a bit curious about this `auto sampleVector(DepthPoints);` What `sampleVector` suppose to be, and what's the type of `DepthPoints`?

Comment: I have a structure `DepthPoint` which holds the x,y,z values for an image.Its structure is   `struct DepthPoint {
        float x;             
        float y;               
        float z;                
        float noise;            
        uint16_t grayValue;     
        uint8_t depthConfidence; 
    }; ` Corresponding to each pixel

Comment: Can you show us how `DepthPoint` is defined?

Comment: you'll get overflows for (float values > 1) * 65536

Comment: should i normalize the float values?

Comment: if values are > 1 yes you should

Comment: I am new to opencv. How can I normalize? i tried to divide using 8, But I am getting an image which is white

Comment: @MariaThomas opencv has a function `cv::normalize`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It worked. :) :)

Comment: Please write your own answer and accept it. And please be careful that normalization might prevent you from making different images comparable. So if 4.0 is the maximum that CAN occur you should better just divide by 4.0 even if no value actually IS 4.0 in that image.

Comment: I have used the `cv::normalize()` function. You mean to say that will also prevent from comparing images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto sampleVector(DepthPoints);
const int size = sampleVector.size();
float* depthValues = new float[size];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sampleVector.size(); i++)
    {
      depthValues[i] = (sampleVector.at(i).z);
    }
Mat depthImageOne, depthImageTwo;
Mat depthImageNew = cv::Mat(var.height, var.width, CV_32FC1,depthValues);
normalize(newDepthImageNew, depthImageOne, 1, 0, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1);
depthImageOne.convertTo(depthImageTwo, CV_16UC1, 65536.0,0.0);
imwrite("path", depthImageTwo);
```

Normalization might cause lose of depth information. I have used normalization for visualization of the images. To preserve the depth information, I used the below code.

```
Mat depthImageNew = cv::Mat(var.height, var.width, CV_32FC1,depthValues);
depthImageOne.convertTo(depthImageTwo, CV_16UC1, 1000.0,0.0);
```